# Trying to make a development instance for a Python pyramid project

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

So I have this Python pyramid-based application, and my development workflow has basically just been to upload changed files directly to the production area.

Coming close to launch, and obviously that's not going to work anymore.

I managed to edit the connection strings and development.ini and point the development instance to a secondary database.

Now I just have to figure out how to create another copy of the project somewhere where I can work on things and then make the changes live.

At first, I thought that I could just make a copy of the project directory somewhere else and run it with different arguments pointing to the new location. That didn't work.

Then, I basically set up an entirely new project called myproject-dev.  I went through the setup instructions:

I used pcreate, and then setup.py develop, and then I copied over my development.ini from my project and carefully edited the various references to myproject-dev instead of myproject.
Then,
initialize_myproject-dev_db /var/www/projects/myproject/development.ini

Finally, I get a nice pyramid welcome page that everything is working correctly.

I thought at that point I could just blow out everything in the project directory and copy over the main project files, but then I got that feeling in the pit of my stomach when I noticed that a lot of things weren't working, like static URLs.

Apparently, I'm referencing myproject in includes and also static URLs, and who knows where else.

I don't think this idea is going to work, so I've given up for now.

Can anyone give me an idea of how people go about setting up a development instance for a Python pyramid project?

Comment: That `/var/www/projects/myproject/development.ini` path worries me - does it mean that if I go to  http://yoursite.com/projects/myproject/development.ini it'll show me the contents of that file, with database password and everything?

Comment: No, I'm just coming from PHP and that was a location that made sense for me. I realize now that it really could go anywhere. I'm running everything by using a full path to the Python virtual environment.  Everything is served by WSGI, and I can't get anything without running the WSGI server

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do, if it's not the case, is version control your project. I'd recommend using git.

In addition to the benefits of managing the changes made to the application when developing, it will aldo make it easier to share copies between developers... or with the production deployment. Indeed, production can just be a `git clone` of the project, just like your development instance.

The second thing is you need to install the project in your Python library path. This is how all the `import`s and `include`s are going to work.

I'd recommend creating a virtual environment for this, with either `virtualenv` or `pew`, so that your app (and its dependencies) are "isolated" from the rest of your system and other apps.

You probably have a `setup.py` script in your project. If not, [create one](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/). Then install your project with `pip install .` in production, or `pip install -e .` in development.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the tips.

I actually do have the project in source control and all of my Python libraries are installed in a virtual environment.

The problem is that I have to reference the project name in various places, for example when I'm importing models:

from myproject.models.meta import DBSession
from myproject.models.users import User
from myproject.models.users import Employee

And also in static references:

${request.static_url(myproject:static/admin/css/main.css')}

I just can't go through during deployment and start searching and replacing my code.

Comment: @JeremyT: You need two separate virtual environments so each can have its individual `myproject` module (and possibly different versions of other libraries your app is using). In addition/alternatively to virtualenv you can have a look at `zc.buildout`. Also have a look at `fabric` as an alternative to deploying via git

Comment: @Sergey was afraid of that, but it makes sense. It just took me forever to get that virtual environment set up

Comment: @JeremyT: the "took forever" part does not sound right - surely it might take a while to set up the first time but after that you should be able to check it out of version control, run a few commands and voila - a copy of your app is set up with all dependencies and everything. My point is - your virtualenv configuration and a list of your app's dependencies should be a part of your project and be version-controlled. This article might provide a starting point: http://www.australsounds.com/2014/04/virtualenvgit-how-to.html

Comment: I see. That's very helpful. I was explicitly keeping my virtual environment out of version control.

I'm having a lot of philosophical difficulties moving from PHP. I like Python, but I get uncomfortable where I have to run magic scripts that do a bunch of things that I can't actually figure out what they are doing.

The thing is though, I do remember reading explicitly that virtual environments can't be moved around, that they must be left in the directory in which they were created. Is that not correct?

Comment: Sure, you should not move vitualenv's auto-generated files, and you should not put them into version control. The configuration (requirements.txt etc.) belongs to the version control though. It should be easy to create a new virtualenv based on the configuration files.  If you find "magic commands" confusing - it's all a matter of modifying Python's `sys.path` so you can even try doing that manually

Comment: @Sergey I'm still a bit confused on what goes into the virtual environment. I went to create a new one, and I had previously put Python, postgres, and all that stuff in the virtual environment.

The problem is that when I go to set up the new virtual environment, I have to install and start the postgres server, which means now I have two servers competing for the same ports on the system. How should I go about deciding what goes in the virtual environment and what doesn't?

Comment: @JeremyT: I'm not even sure how it is possible to install Postgres or Python inside a virtualenv - usually you use pip to install your app's dependencies (Python libs) in a virtualenv so they're isolated from the rest of the system and the setup can be replicated later. Postgres or the actual Python interpreter are not a part of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I managed my last Pyramid app:

I had both a `development.ini` and a `production.ini`. I actually had a `development.local.ini` in addition to the other two - one for local development, one for our "test" system, and one for production.  I used git for version control, and had a main branch for production deployments.  On my prod server I created the virtual environment, etc., then would pull my main branch and run using the `production.ini` config file.  Updates basically involved jumping back into the virtualenv and pulling latest updates from the repo, then restarting the pyramid server.